# build a skeleton screen in css where border doesn't reflects

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to build a skeleton screen in css
- so I referred the below link
  https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/
- but the problem is in my react app its not working.
- I am able to see the html div code but not able to see the css changes.
- I debugged by putting border but still its not working.
- can you guys tell me how to fix.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kjhuv7?file=card.scss

```
.card {
  width: 280px; 
  border: red;
  height: var(--card-height);

  &:empty::after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius:6px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 45px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    background-color:  brown;

    background-image:
      linear-gradient(
        90deg, 
        rgba(lightgrey, 0) 0, 
        rgba(lightgrey, .8) 50%, 
        rgba(lightgrey, 0) 100%
      ),                          //animation blur
      var(--title-skeleton),      //title
      var(--desc-line-skeleton),  //desc1
      var(--desc-line-skeleton),  //desc2
      var(--avatar-skeleton),     //avatar
      var(--footer-skeleton),     //footer bar
      var(--card-skeleton)        //card
    ;

    background-size:
      var(--blur-size),
      var(--title-width) var(--title-height),
      var(--desc-line-1-width) var(--desc-line-height),
      var(--desc-line-2-width) var(--desc-line-height),
      var(--avatar-size) var(--avatar-size),
      100% var(--footer-height),
      100% 100%
    ;

    background-position:
      -150% 0,                      //animation
      var(--title-position),        //title
      var(--desc-line-1-position),  //desc1
      var(--desc-line-2-position),  //desc2
      var(--avatar-position),       //avatar
      var(--footer-position),       //footer bar
      0 0                           //card
    ;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: loading 1.5s infinite;
    background-color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes loading {
  to {
    background-position:
      350% 0,        
      var(--title-position),  
      var(--desc-line-1-position),
      var(--desc-line-2-position),
      var(--avatar-position),
      var(--footer-position),
      0 0
    ;
        background-color:  yellow;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Javascript the word `class` is **reserved** meaning that inside your JSX code you cannot include that word because it is confused with the `class` keyword of Javascript. 
JSX code is not really Javascript and it is later **compiled** so that the javascript runtime understands it.

So, use `className` instead of `class` to set a CSS class of an element:

`<div class="card"> card data</div>`

becomes

`<div className="card"> card data</div>`

Comment: thanks for your reply I updated in stackblitz but still its not working, can you update in my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kjhuv7?file=index.js

Comment: it seems that I cannot save the project

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9wxhvw the issue was that you weren't able to see the effect because it is loading fast. I have put a timeout function for you to see the effect

Comment: thanks can you explain by comments so that it will help me in understanding

Comment: it worked is it possible to put everything in css instead of scss

Comment: I have added some comments explaining the timeout function for simulation purposes (remove in production). For the css I recommend installing the scss compiler npm package and do it locally on your computer. Run `npm install -g sass ` on your terminal and then `sass card.scss card.css`

Comment: hey can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750902/passing-enter-key-event-completion-from-the-chip-component-to-the-tab-component